# How to get client's computer name

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I saw this question in another post but the solution did not work correctly.
I use:

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables.Item("REMOTE_HOST")).HostName
```

This worked correctly on localhost but on server it has problems and returns an empty string.
Any idea?

Comment: I think you'll find that the client's computer name is not available to your on the server, due to standard security.  I certainly wouldn't want my machine name to be transmitted as part of a page request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take into account that `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables.Item("REMOTE_HOST"`) will return the name of the host making the request, not the address.

Try doing `System.Net.Dns.GetHostByAddress(Request.ServerVariables.Item("REMOTE_HOST")).HostName` instead.

You can find a [list of the Server Variables at Microsoft's MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I find out that already in VS2010 "GetHostByAddress" is deprecated.
Instead, use: `System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"])`

Answer (score 0):

To get client IP address use

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.ToString
```

or

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName
```

To get client browser use

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser
```

Comment: OP wants the computer name, not the computer IP address.