# How can i get the PC Name of a client Machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

There is any way to get the PC Name of a client Machine in web application, who is working in different Network, in c# asp.net ?

"This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server. showing this error.
By doing the answer  given in this
[How to get client's computer name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269268/how-to-get-clients-computer-name) ,

Comment: maybe [link](https://www.neerajcodesolutions.com/2018/01/how-to-get-machine-name-in-aspnet-c.html)

Comment: @Dohab I think the OP want the client machine name not the server machine name

Comment: Either you have means of translating the client's IP address to a host name (will however not work if NAT is used), or you find a way to pass this information e.g. in the HTTP headers.

Comment: You really for all practical purposes can't do this - browsers are sandboxed. Even upon a file upload you can't even get the file path name, but only the file name. You can get browser type, current zoom level, and current screen dimensions. But os information, and computer name not really possible - few exceptions exists - such as a browser running ActiveX which no one really allows these days.

Comment: Why do you think you need it?

Comment: @Dohab: Already I tried this in locally it is getting. when I put in main server it is not working.

Comment: @user18387401: this i need to make the site open only in the PC , ie, the PC which is used to register

Comment: @m.r226  "This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server"  showing this error.  < in local server if we uploaded it is working, when we input in the global it is not working"

Comment: If you want to identify “the PC which is used to register” then you need to use accounts with passwords or certificates. “PC Name” is neither unique nor persistent, and can be changed by the client any time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
string clienIp = Request.UserHostName;
string computenMame = CompName(clientIp);

public static string CompName(string clienIp)
{
      IPAddress myIP = IPAddress.Parse(clienIp);
      IPHostEntry GetIPHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(myIP);
      List<string> compName = 
      GetIPHost.HostName.ToString().Split('.').ToList();
      return compName.First();
}
```

Comment: Showing this Eror "This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server"

Comment: Interesting - any additional information as to the limitations of this? Do users have to be on same network or will this work for a general hosted asp.net site?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal , users using different networks, ( if on the same network it is working fine), but with different network it will not working.